# 'NULL' value of VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL is treated as null when bq load

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried to load csv files into bigquery table. There are columns where the types are VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL and some values are 'NULL'. So when I use the command bq load to load, got the following error:

Error while reading data, error message: 'NULL' is null for required

I want to treat the 'NULL' value as NOT NULL.
I am wondering what are the best solutions to deal with this.

Comment: Whence is this CSV file?  I don't know BQ, but is `'NULL'` the marker for a `NULL` value when you write a BQ table to file?  You need to check on this; maybe the current behavior is what is supposed to be happening.

Comment: Thanks, 
I got the following problem and set '--null_marker="NULL"'.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384433/bigquery-could-not-parse-null-as-int-for-field

Comment: I want to solve both problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this kind of cases it's better to treat the data before importing it to BigQuery. You can use [Cloud Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/) to treat the `NULL` values and transform them into empty strings or whatever you see fit. You can follow these steps:

> 1. In the Cloud console go to Dataprep
> 2. Create a Flow
> 3. Add a Dataset (import CSV file)
> 4. Create a new Recipe
> 5. Under transformation select "Replace"
> 6. Select the origin data column
> 7. Under Match pattern add the following regex `/^$/` (this will match empty strings)
> 8. Select the new string value you see fit

After the job is finished you can export the results as csv and import it to BigQuery.

Note that Dataprep treats the `NULL` values as `MISSING` as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Manage-Null-Values_57344568)